# genealogytree: no child for a second marriage in the heart of a genealogy tree

Tags: genealogytree

I have to describe this tree:

`Father` and `Mother` had a child `Daughter`.

`Daughter` married `Husband`.

`Husband` married previously `Other wife` and has `Child` with `Other wife`.

If I write

```
child{
  g{Father}
  p{Mother}
  child{
    g{Daughter}
    p{Husband}
    union{
     g{Other wife}
     c{Child}
    }
  }
}
```

`Child` is connected to `Daughter` and `Other wife` instead to be connected to `Husband` and `Other wife`. Can you help me please to give `Husband` what is `Husband`'s?

Answer (score 2):

There are only tree kinds of trees with genealogytree: *child, parent* and *sandclock*.

When you want to include extensions to relatives outside of that you need to make several trees and then connect them. Here are two trees connected by having the same person "Daughter" in both of them and putting her/them in the same position. The second tree has "Husband" as main person, so can include the extra persons.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree{
  child{
    g{Father}
    p{Mother}
    child{
      % p{Husband}
      g[id=daughter1]{Daughter}
    }
  }
}
\genealogytree[
set position=daughter2 at daughter1]{
  child{
    p[pivot=parent]{Other wife}
    g{Husband}
    c{Child}
    union{
      p[id=daughter2]{Daughter}
    }
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this but the first tree is very large and all the placement of nodes is perturbed around Daughter. I finally eliminate Other wife, to represent Daughter and Husband as parents of Child, remove parent link from Daughter to Child and I reconstruct manually the link from Daughter to Husband.  
    [...]
    \genealogytree[remove parent=D from F]{
      child{
        g{Father}
        p{Mother}
        child[id=F]{
          p[id=H]{Husband}
          g[id=D]{Daughter}
          c{Child1}
          c{Child2}
        }
      }
    }
    \draw (H.east) -- (D.west);
   [...]

Answer (score 0):

What about making husband as the g node ?

```
child{
  g{Father}
  p{Mother}
  child{
    p{Daughter}
    g{Husband}
    union{
     g{Other wife}
     c{Child}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you show an image of the result, too by editing it!? Thank you.

Comment: This solution does not work. Husband becomes the child of Father/mother instead of Wife.